# Cisco ISR 1100 basic configuration

Tags: networking, router, cisco-router

I'm trying to setup my new home network with some cisco devices. I am new with configuration of business network devices, but I want to learn to work with them. But I have basic problems with my Cisco C1111-8P since more than 2 weeks and I get no solution for it.

The Cisco Router is connected with the ETH 0/0/0 port (configured as WAN) to the router of my ISP. I get an IP address (192.168.1.11) from the ISP router and I think the router has access to the internet. When I connect my notebook to one of the LAN ports (ETH 1/0/6) my notebook gets an IP address (e.g. 10.19.14.10) of the defined DHCP pool from the Cisco router. But I cannot get internet access with my notebook.

This is my actual Cisco router configuration.

```
!
! Last configuration change at 22:37:58 UTC Mon Aug 12 2019
!
version 16.9
service config
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
platform qfp utilization monitor load 80
no platform punt-keepalive disable-kernel-core
!
hostname NEXUS-1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
enable secret 5 XXXXXXXX
enable password XXXXXXXX
!
no aaa new-model
!
ip name-server 192.168.1.1
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.14.14.1 10.14.14.9
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.14.14.250 10.14.14.254
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.19.14.1 10.19.14.9
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.19.14.250 10.19.14.254
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.2.14.1 10.2.14.9
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.2.14.250 10.2.14.254
!
ip dhcp pool NEXNET
 network 10.14.14.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 10.14.14.1 
 dns-server 10.14.14.1 
!
ip dhcp pool SkyNET
 network 10.19.14.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 10.19.14.1 
 dns-server 10.19.14.1 
!
ip dhcp pool bitNET
 network 10.2.14.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 10.2.14.1 
 dns-server 10.2.14.1 
!
!
!
ipv6 unicast-routing
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
subscriber templating
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-2759056948
 enrollment selfsigned
 subject-name cn=IOS-Self-Signed-Certificate-2759056948
 revocation-check none
 rsakeypair TP-self-signed-2759056948
!
!
crypto pki certificate chain TP-self-signed-2759056948
 certificate self-signed 01 nvram:IOS-Self-Sig#5.cer
!
license udi pid C1111-8P sn XXXXXXXX
no license smart enable
!
diagnostic bootup level minimal
!
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
!
username YYYYYYYY privilege 15 password 0 XXXXXXXX
!
redundancy
 mode none
!
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 description Internet
 ip address dhcp
 negotiation auto
 ipv6 enable
 ipv6 nd autoconfig default-route
 ipv6 dhcp client request vendor
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
 description Intranet
 ip address dhcp
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/0
 description SkyNET
 switchport access vlan 200
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/1
 description bitNET
 switchport access vlan 400
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/2
 description SkyNET
 switchport access vlan 200
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/3
 description bitNET
 switchport access vlan 400
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/4
 description SkyNET
 switchport access vlan 200
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/5
 description bitNET
 switchport access vlan 400
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/6
 description SkyNET
 switchport access vlan 200
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1/7
 description bitNET
 switchport access vlan 400
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
!
interface Vlan100
 description NEXNET
 ip address 10.14.14.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan200
 description SkyNET
 ip address 10.19.14.1 255.255.255.0
!
interface Vlan400
 description bitNET
 ip address 10.2.14.1 255.255.255.0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
ip http server
ip http authentication local
ip http secure-server
ip http client source-interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 GigabitEthernet0/0/0
!
!
!
!
snmp-server community XXXXXXXX RO
!
!
control-plane
!
!
line con 0
 transport input none
 stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
 password XXXXXXXX
 login
!
ntp server ip 0.de.pool.ntp.org prefer source GigabitEthernet0/0/0
ntp server 1.de.pool.ntp.org source GigabitEthernet0/0/0
ntp server 1.ciscosb.pool.ntp.org source GigabitEthernet0/0/0
ntp server ip 0.ciscosb.pool.ntp.org source GigabitEthernet0/0/0
!
!
!
!
!
end
```

Is there something wrong in my configuration Could anyone help me what is missing in my configuration to get it work?

Comment: See this page....https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/1100/software/configuration/xe-16-7/cisco_1100_series_swcfg_xe_16_7_x.html

Comment: Thank you for the link to the documentation.

With this site I have had done my current configuration. But it do not work to get connection to the internet from a LAN port.

Could you see what is wrong or missing in my configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have get the solution on the Cisco forum.
Pherhaps this could help someone: https://community.cisco.com/t5/routing/cisco-isr-1100-basic-configuration/m-p/3909632

Comment: Maybe you could post exactly what was wrong with your config, so someone looking in the future can see the problem too.

Comment: The problem was, that I have tried to do the configuration over the Cisco WebUI. But some important settings are not available in the WebUI. I had to define my VLAN NAT configuration (`ip nat inside`) via terminal.